# What system fonts should not be deleted?

Tags: fonts

I would like to remove a lot of fonts that have come pre-installed with elementary os, as I wish to install fonts that I have purchased for design work instead.

**What system fonts should not be deleted?** (i.e. Fonts that are required for the running of the operating system)

Comment: Most of pre-installed fonts are necessary for correct system work.

Comment: some font are special characters for debug or other critical system parts, so is not recommended to uninstall them

Comment: @Alexandr Thanks, is there anyway of perhaps hiding system fonts from the drop down menus of apps. I.e. I dont want to have to sift through a crazy list when using Inkscape or other programs. I'm guessing the answer below isn't an exhaustive list then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Elementary OS System Fonts:**

- Default Font:   Droid Sans Regular
- Document Font:  Open Sans Regular
- Monospace Font: Droid Sans Mono Regular
- Titlebar Font:  Droid Sans Bold

I recommend you to save all system fonts in a separate directory if something fails.

Comment: New default terminal font in Loki is Roboto Mono